# tabular cell alignment rotated contents

Tags: tables, rotating

How can rotated table headers be left justified?

Currently have this:

[image: current, wrong situation]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt,twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l r c c c c c c c}
        \textbf{bla1}&\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{bla2}}&\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{bla3}}}&\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{blablablablablabalbal4}}}\\
        \textbf{\textit{bla5}}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Would ideally obtain the following:
[image: Ideal result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt,twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l r c c c c c c c}
       \makecell[bc]{\textbf{bla 1} \\ \textbf{\textit{bla 5}}} &\textbf{bla2}&\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{bla3}}&\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{blablablablablabalbal4}}&\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of the `multirow` commands, I have used the `makecell` package.

To vertically center `bla 2` with respect to `bla 1`and `bla 5` , you could use `\raisebox{5pt}{\textbf{bla2}}`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

with use of `thead` and `\rothead` from `makecell` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, rotating}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lb}

\begin{document}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont blablablablablabalbal4}
    \begin{tabular}{l r c c }
\thead{bla1\\ bla5} & \thead{bla2}  & \rothead{bla3} & \rothead{blablablablablabalbal4}
    \\  \hline
a                   &   b           &   c            & d    
    \end{tabular}

\bigskip
    \begin{tabular}{l r c c }
\thead{bla1\\ bla5} & \thead[t]{\raisebox{1.2ex}{bla2}} & \rothead{bla3} & \rothead{blablablablablabalbal4}
    \\  \hline
a                   &   b           &   c            & d
    \end{tabular}

\bigskip
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont blablabalbal4}
    \begin{tabular}{l r c c }
\thead{bla1\\ bla5} & \thead[t]{bla2} & \rothead{bla3} & \rothead{blablabla blablabalbal4}
    \\  \hline
a                   &   b           &   c            & d
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

personally i prefer solution on the top and on the bottom (if you can break header title into two lines).

Answer (score 2):

One might use the `\rothead` command from `makecell`. Unfortunately you generally have to specify the value of `\rotheadsize` if you don't want untimely line breaks in the rotated head. Furthermore, you can't use the placement specifiers `[bc]` and similar. So I defined a `\myrothead` command  which takes two optional arguments: the placement of the rotated cell (`cc` by default), and the rotation angle (`90` by default):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt,twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{xparse}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myrothead}{O{cc}O{90}m}{\renewcommand{\theadalign}{#1}\renewcommand{\cellrotangle}{#2}
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\theadfont#3} \rothead{#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Rotated heads}
  \begin{tabular}{l r c c c c c c c}
    \toprule
    \thead[bc]{bla 1 \\ \textit{bla 5}} &\thead[bc]{bla2}& \myrothead[bc]{bla3}& \myrothead[bc]{blablablablablabalbal4} \\
    \midrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]