# Modifying alignment of rotated text in tabular figure

Tags: tables, alignment

I've been trying to fix this but to no avail. Is there a way to move the alignment of the rotated text in the attached figure? [image: as shown in the attached figure]
I'm using LLNCS document class. My current code is

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{figure*}[t!]
% \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Unhyperlink}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{c c c c c}
\rothead{{Hyperlink}}    &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth]{img.jpg}  
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth]{img.jpg}\\  
                        % \addlinespace[1pt]
                        % \hline
\rothead{{Unhyperlink}} &   \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth]{img.jpg}\\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Contoh}
\label{fig_seq}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Welcome! This is not really a compilable example. Can you make it compilable?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359290/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409223/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507824/197451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use (and load) [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) if you're not going to insert an `X`-column. Also, rather set elements based on `\linewidth` (or `\textwidth`), not `\paperwidth`. A vertical mis-alignment in the indices (`Hyperlink` and `Unhyperlink`) is corrected by rotating a `\smash`ed version, together with a `c`entred `v`ertical `align` thanks to [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox).

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
    ~\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\smash{Hyperlink}}~~
        \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} \\ \\
    ~\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\smash{Unhyperlink}}~~
        \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `valign=c` option from the `adjustbox` package that you already load:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %<---- remove demo option in real document
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[t!]
% \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Unhyperlink}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{c c c c c}
\rothead{{Hyperlink}}    &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth, valign=c]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth, valign=c]{img.jpg}  
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth, valign=c]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth, valign=c]{img.jpg}\\  
                         \addlinespace
                        % \hline
\rothead{{Unhyperlink}} &   \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth, valign=c]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth, valign=c]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth, valign=c]{img.jpg}
                        &  \includegraphics[width=0.13\paperwidth, valign=c]{img.jpg}\\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Contoh}
\label{fig_seq}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```